# dc.js - Is it possible to exclude graph from a few but not all filters?

Tags: dc.js

I would like to exclude a LineChart from updating if I filter using Pie-Chart-1 but would like it to update however if I filter using Pie-Chart-2.

Hopefully that makes sense, if not I will to get a jsfiddle sorted to show an example but currently having a problem getting onto the site.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you want Pie-Chart-1 to filter other graphs or disable filtering from it entirely? Seems like you could end up in an inconsistent state if you allow it to filter other graphs.

Comment: i would like Pie-Chart-1 to filter a couple of other charts yes.The line chart would only filter on that one pie chart or it should just display data with no filtering.

Comment: I don't think you can do this while using one crossfilter, since it only has the capacity for one set of filters. You might be able to do something like this by using multiple crossfilters.

Comment: @Gordon Please see if the answer logic holds true. I tested it and it worked but not sure if it could cause any glitches somewhere in the way data is processed.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that the pie charts dont filter each other out as well.
In that case you can assign separate dc render events to the chart sets which you want to filter. Assuming you have pieChart1, pieChart2, lineChart1, lineChart2
and you want lineChart1 to update only on selecting a pieChart1 Slice and similarly for the pieChart2 - lineChart2 combo.

Define your charts and give the charts with same filtering a same render event name.

```
var pieChart1 = dc.pieChart("#pie1", "filterView1");
var lineChart1 = dc.lineChart("#line1", "filterView1");

var pieChart2 = dc.pieChart("#pie2", "filterView2");
var lineChart2 = dc.lineChart("#line2", "filterView2");
```

And then finally after defining your chart properties, call two separate render events

```
dc.renderAll("filterView1");
dc.renderAll("filterView2");
```

This way you can make your own render groups for custom filtering.

Comment: I've not tried this yet but will give it a go when I can!

Comment: These are called "chart groups", although it would be nice to have a term that's more clear what it's for like "render event". :-) Unfortunately I don't think this will work past the first click, because if all the charts are still on the same crossfilter, then they will all observe the filters of all of the other charts. So I think you have solved the interaction part but not the data part. Once the second chart group updates because of changes to its own filters, you will see the effects of the filters from the first group.

Comment: @Gordon You are right. I didnt test that part. What you said is the answer after all, multiple crossfilter instances. That checks out. I guess i have some more time to go before i start answering questions :-)